# How to compare two text files with unsorted, and slightly different lines

Tags: linux, windows, diff

I have 2 files like below:

**File1**

```
the quick brown fox jumps
jumps over the very lazy dog
brown fox jumps over the
lorem ipsum dolor
```

**File2**

```
jumps over the very lazy *chicken*
brown fox jumps over the
the quick brown fox *swims*
an apple a day keeps the doctor away
```

I needed to DIFF two files and extract from them the unique lines present in either of the two.

But the problem is:

1. ALL lines in both files are unsorted
2. Lines may (or may not) be the same
3. In comparing lines, the first FOUR words are important. Fifth word onward is "don't care". In the example above, the lines with *chicken* and *swims* in File1 are considered "PRESENT" in File2.

So, based on the conditions above, expected output would be:

**File1**

```
lorem ipsum dolor
```

**File 2**

```
an apple a day keeps the doctor away
```

Anyone know of a way to DIFF this quickly and efficiently? (shortest solution, with easily readable output) What I've tried is visually comparing the two files side-by-side using excel. But I'm gonna do this to a **LOT** of pair of log files. Its gonna take forever to finish them all.

Any better suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write a little program for the job, so it works on *both* platforms? It's easily accomplished in some platform-independent C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Line
{
    char *line;
    char *tokens;
    size_t nwords;
    const char **words;
} Line;

char *copyString(const char *s)
{
    char *r = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (!r) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    strcpy(r, s);
    return r;
}

int compareLines(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const Line *line1 = a;
    const Line *line2 = b;

    size_t mw = line1->nwords;
    if (line2->nwords < mw) mw = line2->nwords;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mw; ++i)
    {
        int r = strcmp(line1->words[i], line2->words[i]);
        if (r) return r;
    }
    if (line1->nwords > mw) return 1;
    if (line2->nwords > mw) return -1;
    return 0;
}

size_t readFile(Line **linesptr, FILE *f, size_t wordCount)
{
    size_t cap = 256;
    size_t n = 0;
    char buf[1024];

    Line *lines = malloc(cap * sizeof(Line));
    if (!lines) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while (fgets(buf, 1024, f))
    {
        if (n == cap)
        {
            cap *= 2;
            lines = realloc(lines, cap * sizeof(Line));
            if (!lines) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        lines[n].line = copyString(buf);
        lines[n].tokens = copyString(buf);
        lines[n].words = malloc(wordCount * sizeof(const char *));
        if (!lines[n].words) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        size_t c = 0;
        char *word = strtok(lines[n].tokens, " \t");
        while (word && c < wordCount)
        {
            lines[n].words[c++] = word;
            if (c == wordCount) break;
            word = strtok(0, " \t");
        }
        lines[n].nwords = c;
        lines[n].words = realloc(lines[n].words, c * sizeof(const char *));
        if (!lines[n].words) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        ++n;
    }
    lines = realloc(lines, n * sizeof(Line));
    if (!lines) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    qsort(lines, n, sizeof(Line), compareLines);
    *linesptr = lines;
    return n;
}

void freeLines(Line *lines, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        free(lines[i].words);
        free(lines[i].tokens);
        free(lines[i].line);
    }
    free(lines);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [n] [file1] [file2]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int nwords = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (!nwords) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    FILE *f1 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (!f1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    FILE *f2 = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    if (!f2) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    Line *f1lines = 0;
    size_t nf1lines = readFile(&f1lines, f1, nwords);
    if (!f1lines) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    Line *f2lines = 0;
    size_t nf2lines = readFile(&f2lines, f2, nwords);
    if (!f2lines) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);

    size_t f1pos = 0;
    size_t f2pos = 0;

    while (f1pos < nf1lines && f2pos < nf2lines)
    {
        int cmp = compareLines(f1lines + f1pos, f2lines + f2pos);
        if (cmp)
        {
            if (cmp < 0)
            {
                printf("%s: %s", argv[2], f1lines[f1pos++].line);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s: %s", argv[3], f2lines[f2pos++].line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ++f1pos;
            ++f2pos;
        }
    }

    while (f1pos < nf1lines)
    {
        printf("%s: %s", argv[2], f1lines[f1pos++].line);
    }

    while (f2pos < nf2lines)
    {
        printf("%s: %s", argv[3], f2lines[f2pos++].line);
    }

    freeLines(f1lines, nf1lines);
    freeLines(f2lines, nf2lines);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you use gcc, compile for example with

```
gcc -s -g0 -O2 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ofinduniq finduniq.c
```

Demo:

```
$ ./finduniq 4 test1.txt test2.txt
test2.txt: an apple a day keeps the doctor away
test1.txt: lorem ipsum dolor

$ ./finduniq 6 test1.txt test2.txt
test2.txt: an apple a day keeps the doctor away
test2.txt: jumps over the very lazy *chicken*
test1.txt: jumps over the very lazy dog
test1.txt: lorem ipsum dolor
test2.txt: the quick brown fox *swims*
test1.txt: the quick brown fox jumps
```

Comment: (In response to platforms stuff) I just have ordinary text files to compare. They're currently in my Windows machine. But basically, if there's a faster way to do it using Linux scripts or something, then I'll just send it all there and do it there. :)

Comment: This seems like a long solution, but I like how "user-friendly" / easily-readable it appears during execution. Will try this out when I get back. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @thisNeil it's still small for a real-life C program and created in less than 30 minutes ;) Of course you can get the same result in less lines using shell scripting on Linux, maybe even with PowerShell on Windows (I'm not too familiar with it), or with a small C# program. perl would be a great tool for problems like that as well. I just like doing it in C because it will compile and run virtually everywhere ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ diff file1 file2 | grep "<\|>" | sed -E 's/^(<|>) //g' | sort | uniq -w5 -u
```

`diff` - compare files `file1` and `file2`,

`grep` and `sed` remove extra lines and symbols, then `sort` strings,

`uniq` outputs unique strings (`-w5` compare first 5 characters in lines, attempt to solve the problem #3 in your list of problems)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I added a description.

Comment: very brief and simple :D Will try this out when I get back. Thanks for the suggestion :)